# Setting UIView dimensions with Bezier Path

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, uibezierpath

i'll preface by saying i'm less than a month into programming with swift.  so i've still heavy in the learning phase and much of the stuff online i've search has been written in Objective-C.

my problem right now is that, I have been using a CA Layer to display images.  (i want to use CA layers because of the animating properties they have that I plan to utilize)

the layer is itself is connect with my UIView like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!

var l: CALayer {
    return myView.layer
}
```

now i have set the UIView in storyboard something like x:100, y:100, w:100, h:100.

but instead of a 100x100 square to put my image into.  I want a polygon shape that I can custom draw with bezier points.

how can i draw the bezier path and set the frame/bound? of the UIView to this custom bezier shape?

this is my first post.  i hope that i phrased this question right and didn't overlook any obvious solutions.

Comment: Have you looked at the subclasses of `CALayer` to see if any seem appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

After creating your `UIBezierPath`, have you tried doing `path.addClip()`? That will serve the purpose I think.